# best way to copy content of NTFS partition to ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, ntfs, ext4

I have a 263 GiB `NTFS` partition (with no free space) and want to copy all its files to a `ext4` partition, that can't be larger than 294 GiB. I also need to copy NTFS Junctions as some kind of link.

Which methods could I use?

**EDIT**:
both partitions are on the same drive. They only contain data. I would have to do the move using Knoppix.

Comment: What is the makeup of your resources? How many physical hard drives are involved? (Where is the source partition, where is the target partition intended to be, where is the OS?)  Which OS are you running?

Comment: Are you working with an OS partition? If it's just data, is there any reason you can't move it using another hard drive?